# Do I need to configure my db server on Capistrano as well as my database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I setup a database instance with Amazon RDS and pointed my production environment of my Rails app in database.yml file to it.  It appears to be working fine.  What's the best way to check?

In my Capistrano recipe, I have the database role still set to my app server.  This is just for capistrano tasks correct?  In a Capistrano task if I migrate the app in the production environment it should still be migrating my RDS server correct?

```
run "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption. The `:db` role is just used for where it will execute the rake task to run the migrations. So if you have:

```
role :db,  "ourmachine.com", :primary => true
```

it will execute the `rake RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate` command on only the primary machine. It uses the database.yml for the location of the server during the migrate task. Many times the `:db` is the same as the `:app` since it can run the migrations.